# I keep getting this error

Tags: actionscript-3

Implicit coercion of a value with static type object to a possibly unrelated number type

but iv defined it in

```
private var width:Object;

public function SetEnemyStartPosition():void
        {
            var stage:Object;
            this.x = stage.stageWidth * .2 - (this.width * .2);
```

Comment: this isn't **java**.

Comment: This is actionscript, retagging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a variable of the generic type `Object`, but you're treating it as a `number`.
From the code provided, it doesn't seem like you ever set a value to the variable `width` which makes the:

```
(this.width * .2)
```

part of your code wrong, it is null, and of the wrong type to do arithmetic operations on to begin with. I'd suggest changing the variable declaration to this:

```
private var width:Number;
```

and making sure `width` isn't null before you start using it.

Comment: Thanks for that but every time i try to launch i get java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using Flexbuilder which is based on eclipse and that something is wrong either with your project or the eclipse installation. Either way, that particular piece of code shouldn't cause that exception. I think Flash (from the CS-package) uses ANT-tasks to compile and build ActionScript code to, I'm not sure though because I havent used flash for ages. It might also have something to do with your java-installation.

Comment: yeah flexbuilder which is now flash builder and built the new actionscript

Comment: Wait a minute now, which is the problem that you want help with, the error `Implicit coercion of a value with static type object to a possibly unrelated number type` or the `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

Comment: Both the other one was another question but i fixed the last one the main.as I must have deleted it for some un-known reason